# Tire ActiveModel callback slow

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, tire

I've a table which shows data from elasticsearch via tire. The table retrieves the data async in json format.
So if i try to change a entry the table still shows the "old" state of the entry (the action redirect directly after save to the index/table). Same when i delete or add an entry.

But this happens just sometimes. I found out that when i add a "sleep(0.3)" to the index action before the data are retrieved it works.

My model:

```
# encoding: utf-8
class Group
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps
  include Tire::Model::Search
  include Tire::Model::Callbacks

  # Relations
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users, index: true
  has_many :group_rights, dependent: :destroy

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :group_rights, allow_destroy: true, autosave: true
  ###

  # Validates
  validates :name, presence: true
  validates :description, presence: true
  ###

  # Mongoid Fields
  field :name, type: String
  field :description, type: String
  ###

  # Elasticsearch
  index_name "#{Tire::Model::Search.index_prefix}groups" # Indexname /initializers/tire.rb
  mapping do
    indexes :_id, :index => :not_analyzed
    indexes :name
    indexes :description
  end

  def to_indexed_json
    to_json
  end 
  ###

  # Methods

  ###

end
```

I think this have something to do with tire callback. But why is this so slow?Is there maybe a better way to update the index accordingly.

I'm using Elasticsearch 0.90 with openjdk-6 on debian squeeze.

Thanks,
Patrick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Elasticsearch doesn't write updates to its index immediately, it has a refresh-interval that defaults to 1 second, so if the write and read are happening in under 1 second then that could be a cause of your problem. You could lower the refresh-interval (I don't advise this) or just call refresh after you write to Elasticsearch in the controller with

```
Tire.index("whatever").refresh
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't knew that. I've added the manual refresh to the controller.

Comment: Be careful though, `refresh` is not without cost. Best is to leave it to Elasticsearch -- unless you really need the changes to propagate immediately, such as in an integration test.

Comment: If you are using [searchkick](https://github.com/ankane/searchkick), you might want to use `Model.searchkick_index.refresh`